# Forced convection: temperature gradient in conical pipe

Tags: air, convection

My situation involves a conical pipe of known dimensions and material composition. Warmer-than-ambient air is added to the small end at a steady, known flow rate.  I'm hoping for a way to estimate interior air temperature at a given time (after warm air begins to be added) and at a given distance (measured from the small end of the pipe).

Comment: No offense, but what expressions or principles have you tried, can you write it in mathjax? I think you need to show this so as to improve the chances of someone helping you out.